# charCodeAt() equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I was wondering if there is a Ruby equivalent of JavaScript's `charCodeAt()` method. The `charCodeAt()` method returns the Unicode value of the character at the specified index in a string.

The following example returns the Unicode value of the last character in a string:

```
str.charCodeAt("HELLO WORLD".length-1)
#=> 68
```

Is there an equivalent for that in Ruby?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [`String#ord`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-ord) methods:

```
'HELLO WORLD'[-1].ord
# => 68
```

It also handles Unicode characters:

```
'aā'[1].ord
# => 257
```